# Windows Server 2008 User Screen Resolution

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, screen-resolution

There are many users that log onto our server (Windows Server 2008 R1) remotely. There is one user in particular that is having trouble seeing her screen due to the resolution set on the server side. She doesn't want to change her computer's resolution and we don't want to change resolution on the server and affect all of the users. Is there any way to change it for her specific user? Thanks and my apologies if this is a silly question!

Answer (score 3):

How are they connecting? If they are using RDP, then the server's console resolution has no bearing on the remote resolution at all. If the troublesome user is using RDP, then look at the RDP settings from her machine.

[image]

If you're not using RDP, then you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: They are connecting through RDP. When they move that Display Configuration slider, it only changes the size of the window not the resolution of what they see on the server. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what screen resolution is. Are you sure that you're not talking about something like font or icon size?

Comment: Maybe I am using the term wrong. I do want the font and icon size to increase. I'm just using the term screen resolution because I know when I change it on my computer, everything gets bigger or smaller.

Comment: Yeah, those are different.